# Can a secret, S, be efficiently recovered from a list of usernames and SHA256(S + username)s?

Tags: sha256, secret-sharing

Given a set of usernames and their corresponding proofs of knowledge of a shared secret: SHA256($SECRET + username), can an attacker recover $SECRET more efficiently than by brute force?

(This is assuming $SECRET is not easily guessable, a 256 bit random string, for example.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This would require a first-order [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) against SHA256.

However, for cases where you wish to key a hash, HMAC constructions are a better choice.